# Printing with XPSDocumentWritter on an Epson printer PrintQueue

Tags: c#, printing, xps

We have an application that have a print function that works well on all printers except some products from Epson on **Windows 8**.
I've manage to make a minimal sample that reproduce the problem.
Call the following method, providing it with the full path to a correct xps file.

```
private void Print(string xpsFilename)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xpsFilename))
  {
    return;
  }

  PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
  printDialog.ShowDialog();
  PrintQueue defaultPrintQueue = printDialog.PrintQueue;

  try
  {
    // This is were it seems to fail for some Epson printers: no job in spooler, no print ...
    PrintSystemJobInfo xpsPrintJob = defaultPrintQueue.AddJob("Print through 'AddJob' on PrintQueue", xpsFilename, false);
  }
  catch (PrintJobException printJobException)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Could not be added to the print queue.", xpsFilename);
    Console.WriteLine(printJobException.Message);
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Unknown error:", xpsFilename);
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
  }
}
```

**You will see that if you choose an Epson printer no job will appear in the spooler whereas it will work with any other printer.**

Does anyone has an idea why it's not printing (the job does not even appears in the spool) ?
In the real application we do not use xps file but rather use a paginator, but for the sample purpose it's simpler and fail too ...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Epson went out the consumer printer business a long time ago.  They now make low-cost point-of-sale printers, the kind you find in a cash registers.  Too slow to use with a standard Windows printer driver, you talk to them [directly](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091), sending native printer commands.  Talk to your friendly Epson distributor for support.

Comment: For people who may encounter the same problem, I opened a microsoft connect ticket that lead to the conclusion that the bug comes from Epson drivers. Epson support should be aware of the issue and we can hope they're gonna fix the bug !?https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/798497/cannot-print-with-some-printers-epson